# How to clear cache of safari in iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, safari, google-signin

Please dont mark as Duplicate because I have tried all things but not working plz some one help me.

My app is having google sign in, while sign in I am getting all the previous signed-in accounts. How to remove those accounts?

Thank you in advance.

```
//MARK:- clear Cache
                URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
                URLCache.shared.diskCapacity = 0
                URLCache.shared.memoryCapacity = 0
                self.deleteCoreData()

                GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().disconnect()
                GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
                for cookie in HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies! {
                    HTTPCookieStorage.shared.deleteCookie(cookie)
                }

                // Removes cache for all responses
                URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
```

Sorry, For duplicate question but I tried above code but its not working. Can please anyone guide me where am I wrong ?
Thank you again.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 3.0, clear all URL cache and cookies like this

```
URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()

if let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies {
    for cookie in cookies {
        HTTPCookieStorage.shared.deleteCookie(cookie)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove specific cookie, related to auth, e.g.:

```
var cookieProperties = [HTTPCookiePropertyKey:String]()
cookieProperties[.name] = "<cookie_name>"
cookieProperties[.domain] = "<domain>"
cookieProperties[.originURL] = "<origin_url>"
// <... etc ...>
if let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: cookieProperties) {
    HTTPCookieStorage.shared.deleteCookie(cookie)
}
```

or just remove all cookies, if it's not a problem in your case:

```
if let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies {
    for cookie in cookies {
        HTTPCookieStorage.shared.deleteCookie(cookie)
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged Swift, not Objective-C. It's best to post answers in the proper language.

Comment: Right, thanks for pointing out. Haven't noticed Swift tag.